# Python pandas: what is the best way to apply operations on the first and last row of a grouping, adding the results as a column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a set of records with startttime and stoptime for workers. I am attempting to subtract the first starttime for a worker by the last stoptime within their shift, but I am unsure how to properly leverage the `first()` and `last()` functions in `Python`. Below is the dataframe `work`:

```
     worker  veh   shift_id              starttime                stoptime
0  11133y   QQUK1   111333         2018-12-21 15:17:29     2018-12-21 15:18:57
1  44706h   FF243   447064         2019-01-01 00:10:16     2019-01-01 00:16:32
2  44706h   FF243   447064         2019-01-01 00:27:11     2019-01-01 00:31:38
3  44706h   FF243   447064         2019-01-01 00:46:20     2019-01-01 01:04:54
4  44761y   LL525   447617         2019-01-01 00:19:06     2019-01-01 00:39:43
5  44842q   OO454   448429         2019-01-01 00:12:35     2019-01-01 00:19:09
6  44842q   OO454   448429         2019-01-01 00:47:55     2019-01-01 01:00:01
7  44842q   OO454   448429         2019-01-01 01:12:47     2019-01-01 02:01:50
8  46090u   OP324   460908         2019-01-01 00:16:23     2019-01-01 00:39:46
9  46090u   OP324   460908         2019-01-01 00:58:02     2019-01-01 01:19:02
```

I am looking to get an output like this:

```
     worker  veh   shift_id              starttime                stoptime       hrs_per_gig
0  11133y   QQUK1   111333         2018-12-21 15:17:29     2018-12-21 15:18:57       .0010
1  44706h   FF243   447064         2019-01-01 00:10:16     2019-01-01 00:16:32       .0379
2  44706h   FF243   447064         2019-01-01 00:27:11     2019-01-01 00:31:38       .0379
3  44706h   FF243   447064         2019-01-01 00:46:20     2019-01-01 01:04:54       .0379
4  44761y   LL525   447617         2019-01-01 00:19:06     2019-01-01 00:39:43       .0143
5  44842q   OO454   448429         2019-01-01 00:12:35     2019-01-01 00:19:09       .0758
6  44842q   OO454   448429         2019-01-01 00:47:55     2019-01-01 01:00:01       .0758
7  44842q   OO454   448429         2019-01-01 01:12:47     2019-01-01 02:01:50       .0758
8  46090u   OP324   460908         2019-01-01 00:16:23     2019-01-01 00:39:46       .0435
9  46090u   OP324   460908         2019-01-01 00:58:02     2019-01-01 01:19:02       .0435
```

In R using `data.table` package this is simple. I do something like this:

```
#my grouping variables
group_by = c('worker', 'veh', shift_id)

#produce a new column that calculates difference in first and last work times in hours
work[
     ,hrs_per_gig:=as.numeric(difftime(last(stoptime),first(starttime), units = "hours"))
     ,group_by]
```

I'm not sure how to achieve the same result in `Python`. I attempted the following:

```
#my grouping variables
group_by = ['worker', 'veh', 'shift_id']

#produce a new column that calculates difference in first and last work times in hours
work['hrs_per_gig'] = df.groupby(group_by).last('stoptime') - 
df.groupby(group_by['starttime'].first()
```

But I got an error `ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the components of `timedelta` objects by doing:

```
grp = df.groupby(group_by)
duration_per_gig = (grp['stoptime'].last() - 
                    grp['starttime'].first()).dt.components
```

Example:

```
In [56]: duration_per_gig = (grp['stoptime'].last() - grp['starttime'].first()).dt.components

In [57]: duration_per_gig                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[57]: 
                       days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
worker veh   shift_id                                                                        
11133y QQUK1 111333       0      0        1       28             0             0            0
44706h FF243 447064       0      0       54       38             0             0            0
44761y LL525 447617       0      0       20       37             0             0            0
44842q OO454 448429       0      1       49       15             0             0            0
46090u OP324 460908       0      1        2       39             0             0            0
```

Comment: Unfortunately the issue with this approach is that it create a new object that I have to join back. My hope was to run this operation in one line like in `R` and add the column directly onto the existing dataframe.

Comment: Ah, ya, I hear that. I'm not a fan of having data duplicated anywhere in a DataFrame if it can be helped. You can look into `.transform()` to see if it will meet your needs.